# How can i type a negative angle

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

How can I type a negative angle? Like this:

[image]

I've been trying a lot of things around `$U\angle\gamma$` but couldn't make it work.

Comment: `$U\angle-\gamma$` works for me, but it does not look nice. U is a Latin letter and should not be used in order to indicate an angular value.

Comment: Yeah, not so nice. But i'll take it for now! Thanks!

Comment: How about this `$U\angle$\raisebox{0.1em}{$-\gamma$}`?

Comment: I am wondering about the syntax as well. What should `$U\angle-\gamma$` indicate? `U` is the negative value of angle `\gamma`?

Comment: Heres what U means:

$\overrightarrow{U} = U\angle\gamma$

But i need to lag this vector in 180º, so i defined a new vector, $\overrightarrow{U^*}$:

$\overrightarrow{U^*} = $U\angle-\gamma

Comment: @MuriloAraujoSouza: Vectors are typeset usually with `\vec` or with `\vv` from `esvect` package, i.e. `\vec{U}^{\asterisk} = -\vec{U}` is usually sufficient in order to indicate the anti-parallel vector

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Oh, didnt knew about that. Thats really nice, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{steinmetz}

\begin{document}

$U\phase{-\gamma}$ $U\phase{-\gamma\mathstrut}$

\end{document}
```

[image]